# run multiple commands while login to linux host

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, command, host

I log in to multiple Linux hosts on everyday basis using my LDAP username and then `sudo su` to ROOT and ORACLE user and check the database status.

As I do this everyday basis on many Linux hosts, I am curious to see whether I can run all commands in single command line?
I tried following, but it didn't help
[how to execute multiple commands after sudo command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340283/how-to-execute-multiple-commands-after-sudo-command)

Example:
After I login using my LDAP user to Linux Host, I want to run following commands in one single command

`sudo su - root -c "su - oracle; ps -ef |grep pmon; crsctl stat res -t "`

After login to root, then need to switch to oracle user and then run commands

Answer (score 0):

The reason your command as written doesn't work is because you don't actually run your monitoring commands as the `oracle` user.

The command you give to the first `su` invocation, `su - oracle; ps -ef | grep pmon; crsctl stat res -t`, attempts to do three things in sequence as `root`: firstly, it calls `su` to spawn an interactive shell as `oracle`; after this shell exits, it runs the `ps` pipeline; finally, it runs the `crsctl` command. Since the monitoring commands run *after* the second `su` has finished, they run as `root`, which isn't what you want.

The smallest change to your command that will make it work is the following:

```
sudo su - root -c "su - oracle -c \"ps -ef | grep pmon; crsctl stat res -t\""
```

(Note that you need to escape the inner pair of quotes with backslashes so that they don't end the outer quoted string.) However, you can simplify this command significantly: the first optimization you can make is to get rid of the first `su` call. You don't need it, because you're already `root` from `sudo`:

```
sudo su - oracle -c "ps -ef | grep pmon; crsctl stat res -t"
```

You can still make it better, though. If `sudo` is configured to allow you to switch to any user (not just `root`), you don't need to use `su` at all. Instead, just specify the user you want using `sudo -u`:

```
sudo -u oracle sh -c "ps -ef | grep pmon; crsctl stat res -t"
```

(Note that you need to add an explicit call to `sh` so that you can run the entire set of commands as `oracle` and not just the first one. `sudo`'s documentation claims that you can use its `-i` or `-s` options for this, but they didn't work as documented in my tests.)

If you want to keep an interactive shell as the `oracle` user after this command, you can simply make the last command `sudo` runs be an interactive shell. In this case, you probably also want to pass `-i` to `sudo` so that the interactive shell has the login environment of `oracle`:

```
sudo -i -u oracle sh -c "ps -ef | grep pmon; crsctl stat res -t; $SHELL"
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. 1. Main reason to login as a root is to run commands as root and as oracle without prompting password again from my ldap.So,I would prefer to first login as root and then switch to Oracle.

2. The above 2 commands run those 'crsctl' and 'ps' command as oracle, but i remain in my ldap account. however, I want login as root first and then oracle and remain in as oracle user to run those commands. could you pls help on this.

Comment: Did you try the commands I gave? None of them should ask for any password apart from the initial `sudo` one, just like your original command. I'm not sure I understand your second point: do you mean that you want to keep an interactive shell as `oracle` after the two commands are run?

Comment: Yes.It doesn't ask password, but it still remain in my ldap session, doesn't login into root-->oracle session.

Yes.I want to login into oracle and remain in the oracle session to run interactive commands...
I dont want to simply run all commands from my ldap user...i want to login as root --> oracle to stay as oracle user

Comment: I edited my answer. Does the last command do what you want?

As an aside, is there a specific reason you want to go from your user to `root` then to `oracle`? The last three commands in my post, as I explained, skip `root` entirely and go straight to `oracle`. If there's some reason you need to go through `root` on the way, let me know and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks Tom for fixing, the last command works, however, i still prefer to login to root first and then oracle to run interactive commands as oracle user. The reason is, there will be many commands to run as root and as oracle. So, if i login as root and switch to oracle, then i will be able to switch back and forth without password. else, i will be on my ldap user session when exit from oracle and `sudo su - root` will prompt for the password.
Please let me know if any questions. Thanks again for your help :)